# On submiting form shows error: get method not supported but when I go back and reload the form it gives me my required output

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, get

This is my view:

```
@extends('admin.layout.form-layout')

@section('page-content')
<div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">

            <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-password-image"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="p-5">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-2">Enter OTP</h1>

                                </div>
                                @if (session()->has('error'))
                                    <span class="text-danger d-block">{{ session()->get('error') }}</span>
                                @endif
                                <form class="user" action="{{ route('otp.fun', $token) }}" method="get">
                                    @csrf
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="otp" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                            id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter OTP">
                                        @error('otp')
                                            <span class="text-danger d-block">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                        Submit
                                    </button>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**This is route**

```
Route::get('/otp/{token}',[AuthController::class,'otpFun'])->name('otp.fun');
```

**This is the function in AuthController**

```
public function otpFun(Request $request,$token){
    $request->validate([
        'otp'=>'min:6|max:6'
    ]);

    if($token==$request->otp){
        $email=DB::table('password_resets')->where('token',$request->otp)->value('email');
        return view('admin.page-content.add-new-password',compact('email'));
    }
    else{
        return back()->with('error','Incorrect OTP, Try Again ');
    }
}
```

When I click on submit button instead of showing the validation error and the content in the if-else it gives me this error:
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/send-reset-mail
but when I go back and refresh the form it gives me my required output but it gives me the error when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

So that's an interesting question. so what i see you are trying to ues get and post in same route, you try to post a data in your action form but in route you put get instead of POST.

If you want to get a data you can use get

```
Route::get('/otp/{token}',[AuthController::class,'otpFun'])->name('otp.fun');
```

and if you want to post a data you need to use post

```
Route::POST('/otp/{token}',[AuthController::class,'otpFun'])->name('otp.fun');
```

you can actuly also use get and post a data in same route by using

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/otp/{token}', 'uthController::class,'otpFun');
```

Comment: Actually there is problem in my route.In the error it is showing me the error in send-reset-mail method while I am in the otp form .So in send-reset-mail method i am returning view of otp form.So instead of returning view i created an other route for otp and I used route instead of view.